# Typing text into mergeFields located in text boxes in Word Document, using Interop.Word

Tags: c#, interop

I've been having this problem for a while now:

I need to enter text into these here fields:

I have managed to enter text into tables in the same document, and into fields located in
the body of the document without any problem, but I just can't get this to word.

http://pokit.org/get/?0ce2677993b3ed9360c4033db89d787f.jpg

That is the text box I have to write in, and I have tried to do so by looping in a foreach loop and accessing shape ID(1039), then changing its textframe text, but nothing.

Thanks again for any help.

EDIT: I have managed to solve it, I will post it later since it doesn't allow me for another 8 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bookmark that textbox with in word doc with a name for eg. 'text1'.
Now access that bookmark & edit the text in your C# project as:

```
Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\test.docx");
Bookmark bkm = wordDoc.Bookmarks["text1"];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = bkm.Range;
rng.Text = "My address is...";
```